# How do I use my headless ubuntu server over ethernet?

Tags: server

I have two computers. Computer A runs Ubuntu desktop. Computer B is headless and runs Ubuntu server. I've got them connected with an Ethernet cable. I want to know how to access the terminal of computer B from computer A as seamlessly as possible through that Ethernet cable.
This is probably easy for most of you, but I am very inexperienced.

Comment: Do any of them have any other network connections? Also, does Computer B have SSH on? Usually you can just pick some (internal) subnet that is NOT your main one and give the two devices two (different) static IPs on that subnet. I.e., if computer A is connected to a normal router on subnet 192.168.1.0/24 with an IP of 192.168.1.53, and computer B has no other connections, you could give computer B the IP of 10.1.1.1 on subnet 10.1.1.0/24 and on A you'd set the IP on the ethernet interface connected to A to be 10.1.1.2 with a subnet of 10.1.1.0/24. Then they should be able to talk to each other

Comment: Do you mean you literally plugged one end of a cable into computer A and the other in computer B? Although it is in theory possible to create a connection that way, that is far more complicated than connecting both machines to a router, as @cocomac explains.